# sonar bitbucket pull diff failed message

Tags: sonarqube, diff, bitbucket, bamboo

I'm using Bitbucket with Sonar and Bamboo and all the latest versions. I have it configured to build and run Sonar on a pull request.

That part works fine. In Bitbucket, I see the Sonar results and the green XXX has passed all quality gates with the metrics under it.

The issue is when I click on the DIFF tab. It shows the diff, but also a big red:

> Sonar for Bitbucket had failed, failed to analyze build project XXX

[image]

Driving me crazy. Any help appreciated!

Localhost log snippet of many similar errors:

```
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.StashFileContentRetriever.getFileContents(StashFileContentRetriever.scala:18) ~[plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.maven.MavenProject.getFileContent(MavenProject.scala:135) [plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.maven.MavenProject.pomToModel(MavenProject.scala:31) [plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.maven.MavenProject.ch$mibex$stash$sonar4stash$sonar$buildinfo$maven$MavenProject$$processModules(MavenProject.scala:42) [plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.maven.MavenProject$$anonfun$ch$mibex$stash$sonar4stash$sonar$buildinfo$maven$MavenProject$$processModules$1.apply(MavenProject.scala:75) [plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.maven.MavenProject$$anonfun$ch$mibex$stash$sonar4stash$sonar$buildinfo$maven$MavenProject$$processModules$1.apply(MavenProject.scala:65) [plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381) [scala-2.11-provider-plugin-0.10.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.maven.MavenProject.ch$mibex$stash$sonar4stash$sonar$buildinfo$maven$MavenProject$$processModules(MavenProject.scala:65) [plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.maven.MavenProject.analyze(MavenProject.scala:24) [plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.BuildProjectsAnalyzer$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BuildProjectsAnalyzer.scala:39) [plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.BuildProjectsAnalyzer$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BuildProjectsAnalyzer.scala:37) [plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-2.11-provider-plugin-0.10.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-2.11-provider-plugin-0.10.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.stash.internal.concurrent.StateTransferringExecutor$StateTransferringRunnable.run(StateTransferringExecutor.java:70) [bitbucket-platform-4.4.2.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
... 46 frames trimmed
2016-04-13 05:56:21,026 ERROR [threadpool:thread-2] jvienneau @1JCQX84x356x15892x0 1x5tg13 10.12.40.146 "GET /rest/sonar4stash/1.0/sonarissues HTTP/1.1" c.m.s.s.s.b.StashFileContentRetriever SONAR: Was not able to read build file dataservice\casenet-dataservice-adapter/pom.xml in repository TC libs of branch hzawil/TEST-1. Will stop analysis now...
com.atlassian.bitbucket.content.NoSuchPathException: The path "dataservice\casenet-dataservice-adapter/pom.xml" does not exist at revision "refs/heads/hzawil/TEST-1"
at com.atlassian.bitbucket.scm.git.command.GitCommandExitHandler.evaluateStdErr(GitCommandExitHandler.java:74) ~[bitbucket-git-4.4.2.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.bitbucket.scm.git.command.GitCommandExitHandler.onError(GitCommandExitHandler.java:156) ~[bitbucket-git-4.4.2.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.bitbucket.scm.DefaultCommandExitHandler.onExit(DefaultCommandExitHandler.java:31) ~[bitbucket-spi-4.4.2.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.bitbucket.scm.BaseCommand.callExitHandler(BaseCommand.java:138) ~[bitbucket-spi-4.4.2.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.bitbucket.scm.BaseCommand$CommandFuture.internalGet(BaseCommand.java:252) ~[bitbucket-spi-4.4.2.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.bitbucket.scm.BaseCommand$CommandFuture.get(BaseCommand.java:221) ~[bitbucket-spi-4.4.2.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.bitbucket.scm.BaseCommand.call(BaseCommand.java:75) ~[bitbucket-spi-4.4.2.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.stash.internal.content.DefaultContentService.streamFile(DefaultContentService.java:129) ~[bitbucket-service-impl-4.4.2.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.plugin.util.ContextClassLoaderSettingInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextClassLoaderSettingInvocationHandler.java:26) ~[atlassian-plugins-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.StashFileContentRetriever.getFileContents(StashFileContentRetriever.scala:18) ~[plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.maven.MavenProject.getFileContent(MavenProject.scala:135) [plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.jar:na]
at ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash.sonar.buildinfo.maven.MavenProject.pomToModel(MavenProject.scala:31) [plugin.805853672496094168.sonar4stash-1.6.1_1459539398878.ja
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the plug-in. I need a stack trace to help you. Could you please have a look at your Bitbucket server log? If you don't want to share a stack trace here, you can also create a bug report in our JIRA project at https://mibexsoftware.atlassian.net/browse/SONAR (which requires to create an account and is therefore closed for anonymous users).

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Thanks, but this stack trace isn't caused by our plug-in (it is from Bitbucket Server itself). Could you please have a look at your log again when you open the diff in the UI? You should then see a stack trace with a message having the prefix "SONAR:" and stack frames containing "ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash".

Comment: And what about stack frames starting with "ch.mibex.stash"?

Comment: Replaced the error log above with the ch.mibex.stash sections from the application log.

Comment: The build file dataservice\casenet-dataservice-adapter/pom.xml is missing in your branch "hzawil/TEST-1". Is that possible? Could you please outline your build structure (in which directories your pom.xml files are located)?

Comment: There is a POM file in that directory. See dependency tree above.

Comment: Are you running Bitbucket Server under Windows? Just because of the backslash in your path....

Comment: Yes, windows, and yes there's a POM file in dataservice\casenet-dataservice-adapter and "mvn validate" runs successfully.